# not able to move scroll bar inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div that gets filled dynamically when the user sends data from form, it is similar to chat box. where the user ends message and that message gets displayed inside the div. Now this div has a scroll bar that should stay at the bottom but if the user scrolls then it should stay at that position where the user has kept it

The issue is that although the scroll bar stays at the bottom but when the user pulls it up, then also it pulls itself to bottom and the user can't use it to scroll.

Code for div

```js
var youInterval;

function startInterval() {

  youInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbody');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
  }, 500);

}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'scrollBottom') {
    clearInterval(youInterval);
  }
}, true);
startInterval();
```

```css
.chatbox__body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox__body" id="scrollbody"></div>
```

Can anyone please help me with the issue

Comment: In your scroll event listener you check for target with Id scrollBottom it should be scrollbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition here is failing  `if (event.target.id === 'scrollBottom') {`

The `event` generated by scroll is on document so, `event.target.id` is actually checking `id` property of document which is not there.

You have to disable overflow in body first and then add overflow to div

```
html,body{  height:100%; width:100%;overflow:hidden;}

.chatbox__body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

In your JS check for `if (event.target.id === 'scrollbody') {`

**SNIPPET**

```js
var youInterval;

function startInterval() {

  youInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbody');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
  }, 500);

}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  debugger;
  if (event.target.id === 'scrollbody') {
    clearInterval(youInterval);
  }
}, true);
startInterval();
```

```css
html,body{  height:100%; width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
.chatbox__body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:100%;
}

#content{
 height:200%;
 width:100%;
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox__body" id="scrollbody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked nicely Thanks